# Make JSP login form more safe

Tags: java, jsp, security, authentication

I'm working on my first website with Eclipse, even if I really do not see any need of the IDE yet. It's created login form, which I think is safe from injection because of use of `PreparedStatement` . I am wondered if there is any other way I can make it safe in simple steps and what are minuses of the algorythm I have now. So, here it is the code:

**login.jsp**

```
<form action="log.jsp">
    <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="userMail"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="userPassword" />
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> 
    Keep me signed in
</span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

**log.jsp**

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String userMail = request.getParameter("userMail");    
    String userPassword = request.getParameter("userPassword");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book_store", "root", "daters");
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userMail=? AND userPassword=?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, userMail);
ps.setString(2, userPassword);
System.out.println(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userMail", userMail);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say it is your first attempt and presumably you want to get better - here are a few things to note.

a) Design Pattern - MVC 
 JSP is the V part of the MVC - your program is MV and C all rolled into a large V.

b) Once you do get around to creating a Model, you may apply additional validations there - Null checks, etc.

c) You will eventually need to hold on to the fact that the user logged in, and use that info across other requests ..

Comment: oh forgot to mention. .have a look at this https://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/downloads/detail?name=OWASP%20Fall%202007%20San%20Jose%20-%20Anti%20Samy.pptx&can=2&q=  . Will give you a good idea of what not to do.

Answer (score 2):

One other thing you might want to improve:

- Don't store passwords as clear texts. Use a *secure* one-way hashcode and compare the hash values.

Example code:

```
MessageDigest digest =    MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```